# Regarding Jasper report bar chart

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm using jasper ireport 4.0.1 for developing. And I need to realize a bar graph being shown according to the imported 2 parameter one is for the used and the other is the total value. I want the left part of this bar represented in red color and the length will be changed according to the proportion of the used value out of the total also the used value need to be shown on this part of bar and the rest of the bar in green colour with the length regarding the total minus by the used value. How can I realize that, any help will be appreciated!

Let say the total value is 45

If the used value is 24 then the bar graph will show as follow

[image]

If the used value is 44 then the bar graph will looks like this

[image]

Regards,

Comment: Could you add some more detail?

Comment: Have added two senarios. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that by defining 2 parameters:

- **max**: maximum value
- **proportion**: value when it should switch between blue and green.

Then you add a stacked bar chart with 3 series:

- **Series1**: series expression: "RED", category expression `$F{<field>}`, value expression `$F{<value>}`
- **Series2**: series expression: "BLUE", category expression `$F{<field>}`, value expression `$F{<value>} < $P{proportion} ? $P{max} - $F{<value>} : 0`
- **Series3**: series expression: "GREEN", category expression `$F{<field>}`, value expression `$F{<value>} >= $P{proportion} ? $P{max} - $F{<value>} : 0`

[image: report output]

Comment: Hi MrsTang, Sorry for confused you in my question. I have repost two senario with graph. Could you have a look to help me out? Thanks

Comment: Hey, no worries. It is pretty much the same, you just remove the case between blue and green and configure the chart for horizontal orientation. Once I'm on a laptop again I'll check for showing the labels on top of the bar.

Comment: Thanks Tang, I tried your way and it works ! Just need your help again for the label on the top of the bar coz the label's position need to be changable according to the value.Thanks a lot !

Comment: Hi Mrs Tang, I have solve the problem, just need to tick the "Show Labels" property in the stackedBargraph. Thanks for you help!